# Sistema de aprovação de posts em php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, mysqli

Estou criando um sistema de aprovação de posts meio na "Gambiarra", o que fiz é, quando o usuario faz uma postagem, ela recebe o valor '0' na tabela 'Status' no banco de dados.

Então, tenho uma página restrita para o adm do site, nessa página tenho um loop que exibe os posts com Status 0 (Posts ainda não aprovados), nesse loop também tenho um botão em cada post que ao clicar irá mudar a tabela Status de '0' para '1'. O problema é que quando clico, ele modifica de todos os posts e não apenas o que estou clicando. preciso de alguma coisa que idenfique apenas aquele post.

Para isso usei um script de javascript, a sequência de tudo vai a seguir:

O loop na página restrita:

```js
<?php while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <div class="post">
          <h2 id="titulo"><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
          
             <p>POSTAGEM</p>
       
          <button type="button" name="button" onclick="myAjax()" >aprovar</button>

        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

O JavaScript na página restrita:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '_controller/approvajax.php',
           data:{id:$("#ajax").val()},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }
      });
    }
</script>
```

O arquivo do ajax:

```
<?php
  include_once('../_inc/conexao.inc.php');

  $up = $conexao->query("UPDATE vagas SET status = 1");
  $up->execute();
 ?>
```

Algum conselho para selecionar apenas aquele post?

Comment: Se você não colocar um `WHERE id = ?` todas as linhas da sua tabela vão ser alteradas.

Comment: E para mandar isso para o Update, você vai ter que colocar isso no teu elemento na hora do while, para que o javascript enxergue esse ID  e consiga inserir isso no update

Comment: Como @rray disse, se você não especificar o id da vaga, todos os registros da tabela vão ser atualizados..

Comment: Ok, posta um exemplo de como deve ficar no loop e na query.

Comment: Emerson, este não é o objetivo deste site. O objetivo não é "fazer o código" para você. Você já chegou a ler o guia do site? [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) / [Que tipos de pergunta devo fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: É pra eu entender como devo fazer, Where id = Qual o valor que eu coloco aqui? qual referência dessa id devo fazer no loop? O objetivo do site é discutir o problema e ajudar o amigo aqui, se exemplificar como deve ser o código correto, o objetivo do site é concluido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa passar o id do elemento que deseja atualizar como parâmetro na chamada da função:

**Código PHP:**

```
        <?php while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
            <div class="post">
              <h2 id="titulo"><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                 <p>POSTAGEM</p>
                 <button type="button" name="button" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="myAjax($(this).data('id'))" >aprovar</button>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Código JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myAjax(idPostagem = null) {
      if (idPostagem) {
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '_controller/approvajax.php',
              data:{id: idPostagem}, // esse parametro é o id que vai ser usado na query?
              success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
              }
         });
      }
    }
</script>
```

**Código SQL:**

```
<?php
  include_once('../_inc/conexao.inc.php');

  $up = $conexao->query("UPDATE vagas SET status = 1 where id = {$_POST['id']}");
  $up->execute();
 ?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago, e respondendo o amigo ali em cima, esse é o objetivo do site, ao invés de passar muito tempo descutindo por texto, apenas postando um exemplo prático o problema é resolvido.

Comment: Se te ajudou, marque a resposta do companheiro como a resposta aceita/correta. Abraço!